# SQL in Crystal gives "blank" but works in SQL Server

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I was asked to add an "as of" date to an Existing Crystal report.

I went into SQL Server (management studio), and figured out how to get a single date meeting the requirement.

Then I copy/pasted the SQL into Crystal's "add command" box.  When I put that field in the report footer, it is empty.  Go back to SQL server, and it still gives the date I expect.

Checked the formatting properties--it isn't that.

Is there a fix for this?

Normally, I would put the SQL in the server as a stored procedure or function, but it's a vendor-supplied DB that I am not allowed to alter.  Can't use profiler for the same reason.

Found a blog article where someone claimed that Crystal demands column names and aliases (but not table names) to be in double quotes.  Found that hard to believe but I tried it.  No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a "feature" of Crystal Reposts.

If the criteria for the detail section of the report are such that no records are shown, then Crystal will not display data that does return for unrelated queries in other sections.

That's obtuse, so an example:

If the report is "all claims this week over a million dollars" and there are none, Crystal will also refuse to render the output of GETDATE().

Answer (score 0):

if stored procedure successfully run in SQL server Management Studio

make sure the final statement in stored procedure using select and explicit declare field name instead of *

try to verify database,
try to preview in crystal report

Comment: Like I said, there is no stored procedure.  And there is no star--"single date"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is something wrong with the Crystal report file itself.  Other people get the same behavior on this file on other machines, but it works when we do the same actions in other files.

Have to build the report again.  Bummer.